# How Do I Set Up Fiscal Trimesters, Anyway?

Tags: soql, custom-fiscal-year, date-literals

I had some fun over the weekend trying to answer this question: **[How do SOQL date literals behave with fiscal years that differ from one year to the next](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/126065/how-do-soql-date-literals-behave-with-fiscal-years-that-differ-from-one-year-to)**.

However, I was kind of shocked by how unintuitive it is to set up trimesters in the first place, and the dearth of examples out there. Most of the answers I saw to similar questions simply pointed to the documentation, which does not really make it clear how to set up trimesters.

Comment: `fiscal trimester` as in three periods per year (e.g. Jan-Apr, May-Aug, Sep-Dec)?

Comment: @crop Yeah exactly that. Well, I mean, I was just trying to answer that guy's question, so your exact implementation needs may vary.

Comment: mind-bending as `Quarter` no longer means something divisible into fourths

Comment: @crop Yeah, kinda fun that way. It's a restricted picklist and I don't think you can modify its available values. You can actually rename the `Period` records though, so it would be `T3` instead of `Q3`, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you need to do in a fresh org:

1. Navigate to `Setup` > `Company Profile` > `Fiscal Year`.
2. Click the <kbd>New</kbd> button.
3. Select any option you want from the **`Select Fiscal Year Structure`** dialog. You're going to butcher it anyway.
   <sub><sup>(5-4-4 may slightly reduce the amount of clicking)</sup></sub>

   [image: Select Fiscal Year Structure dialog]
4. Click the <kbd>Continue</kbd> button.
5. Now for the fun part that I found least obvious. My eyes simply seemed to slide right past the collapsed dropdown for **`Advanced Customizations`**. Expand it, this section is where you will do the rest of your work.

   [image: Custom Fiscal Year Definition screen]
6. Note that there are `Period` definitions at three different levels: `Quarter`, `Month`, and `Week`.

   [image: Customization Structure]
7. Delete one of your `Quarter` definitions. First select the row, then click the <kbd>Delete</kbd> button.

   [image: Delete Quarter 4]
8. One at a time, add the months back in. First, select the last month of a quarter (trimester), then click the <kbd>Insert</kbd> button.

   [image: Insert April]

   [image: Insert August]

   [image: Insert December]
9. Set up your months to have the correct number of days. Every month except February (on non-leap years) should have five weeks. 30 day months should have 2 days in the final week. 31 day months should have 3 days in the final week.

   [image: January 31 days]